# Reputation requirements unchanged for the Meta site?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, meta, privileges

So originally, I was going to post that the "links" tab used by 10k users still says "2000" reputation, but only 3 people can actually vouch for that. And it turns out it's only on the Meta site; the parent site properly says 10,000 reputation. I did some extra digging, and our FAQ also has the old reputation limits.

According to [Sam Saffron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66866/math-sx-faq-says-750-needed-for-closing-privilege-ive-got-the-power-at-rep-743/66870#66870), the reputation requirements on the FAQ are now linked to the actual site privilege levels, instead of being static text. The [Web Application Site's Meta FAQ](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) has the correct levels, and the tools link still does say 2000, so I'm thinking it's not a simple error of the FAQ being not updated but that the Meta hasn't been updated.

I can't actually confirm, though. We don't have access to a separate privileges page for the Meta site.

Comment: Bug confirmed. I still can access the meta tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was our mistake -- should be fixed now.